# Explanation to debugger warning using DSLCalendarView in iOS8

Tags: ios

I am updating an app to iOS8. The app has a DSLCalendarView integrated. It works fine in iOS 7 and prior versions.
Now I am updating the app and the view controller that should show the custom DSLCalendar, it shows a warning at debugging:

```
 "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x14dc2c30 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(43)-[UIButton:0x14dbc780]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14dc0160 )>",
            "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x14dc2c90 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UIButton:0x14dbc780(79)]>",
            "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x14dc40f0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x14dbc780.midY == + 72>"
```

At running, only the first two rows respond to the tap gesture. I am sure it is an issue due to the custom view constrains or size. I am trying to insert the DSLCalendarView as a custom view.

Any help is welcome to understand the debugger warning message

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I have centered the view horizontally and vertically using auto layout, and now it works fine.

Thank you.